# How to tag everyone in the chat by my telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need to tag everybody in chat where my bot added.
My bot writes: @all and it should tag everybody in the chat.
I don't see any Telegram API methods to get all users in specific chat. How should I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are various obstacles that don't let you mention everyone in a single message:

- You can only have up to 50 mentions in each message.[[1]](https://limits.tginfo.me/en)
- **You cannot fetch a list of all members in a chat using a bot.**

If you insist on doing this, you should use a database to collect information about the members of these chats, when they send messages. And afterward, you should send multiple messages to mention all of them 50 by 50.

If you want a simple way to notify all members, you can just pin a message.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it is possible to parse all the chat members.

You can use `client.iter_participants(chat)` in telethon library for this.